# The output for average is not correct

Tags: c

1. The average which is the last output should display 60 but I got it wrong. What is the error here? Here is the temperature input 72, 46, 90, 20, 70 85, 60, 40, -1000.
2. The total hot days should display 2 but on the output I got 3.

   ```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int categorize_days(int temp);

    int categorize_days(int temp){
    if (temp >= 85){
    return 1;
    }
    else if(temp >=60){
    return 2;
    }
    else{
        return 3;
    }
    }

    int main(){

    int i, temp, h, p,c, temp_ave=0, type_days;
    double ave; 

    printf("Lets check the whether !\n");
    printf("Keep entering the integer temperature, enter -1000 to quit\n\n");

    printf("Temperature: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);

    while(temp!= -1000){

    for(i = 0; i<8; i++ ){
    temp_ave =+ temp;
    }
    type_days = categorize_days(temp);

    if( type_days == 1){
        printf ("Day: h\n\n");
        h++;
    }
    else if(type_days == 2){
        printf ("Day: p\n\n");
        p++;
    }
    else{
        printf ("Day: c\n\n");
        c++;
    }

    printf("Temperature: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    }
    printf("End\n\n");


    ave = temp_ave/8;
    printf("Total Hot days: %d \n", h);
    printf("Total Pleasant days: %d \n", p);
    printf("Total Cold days: %d \n", c);
    printf("Average temperature for 8 days is %f", ave);
   }
   ```

Comment: `for(i = 0; i<8; i++ )` Why are you adding the *same* `temp` 8 times?

Comment: Why are you hardcoding `8`? Count the number of values that are read instead of using a hard coded number.

Comment: Why do you need that loop at at all? `while(temp!= -1000)` is the loop. And as commented you should count the inputs instead of assuming there are `8`. That is *why* there is a sentinel vlaue `=1000`.

Comment: @kaylum I thought it would add a different value since I put 'scanf' at the end of the loop

Comment: The `scanf` is way way outside the `for` loop. The only thing the `for` loop body does is add the `temp` value each time. 8 times.

Comment: If you take out the verbiage, you get `scanf("%d", &temp); while(temp != -1000) { total += temp; count++; scanf("%d", &temp); }`

Comment: ohh i forgot to add the on the question. It should also count average for the first 8 days.

Comment: `int h, p, c` ==> `int h=0, p=0, c=0`. The compiler should be warning you about that.

Comment: unknown, Tip: rather than "but I got it wrong.", also post your true result and what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use magic numbers in the code, following and updating becomes tedious. Use `#define` macros as necessary.

```c
#define HOT_CUTOFF  85  // Fahrenheit
#define COLD_CUTOFF 60  // Fahrenheit
#define INPUT_GUARD -1000
```

2. Make use of `enum` to list out `day-types`:

```c
enum {
    eHotDay  = 1,
    eColdDay = 2,
    eCozyDay = 3
} eDayType;
```

3. Then your `day_type()` would change to :

```c
int day_type (const int temp) {
    if (temp >= HOT_CUTOFF)
        return eHotDay;
    else if (temp <= COLD_CUTOFF) // should be less than or equal to
        return eColdDay;
    else
        return eCozyDay;
}
```

4. Always initialise variables before usage. `h`, `p` & `c` are being used without initialisation. Also, `temp_ave` is misleading name for keeping total.

```
int i, temp, h, p,c, temp_ave=0, type_days;
```

5. Why limit only to `8` inputs when you've `-1000` as guard?

Simplified:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define HOT_CUTOFF  85  // Fahrenheit
#define COLD_CUTOFF 60  // Fahrenheit

enum {
    eHotDay  = 1,
    eColdDay = 2,
    eCozyDay = 3
} eDayType;

//int categorize_days (int temp);   // redundant as you're defining the function before usage

//int categorize_days (int temp) {
int day_type (const int temp) {
    if (temp >= HOT_CUTOFF)
        return eHotDay;
    else if (temp <= COLD_CUTOFF) // should be less than or equal to
        return eColdDay;
    else
        return eCozyDay;
}

int main() {

    printf ("Keep entering the integer temperature, enter -1000 to quit\n\n");
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int hot = 0, cold = 0, cozy = 0;
    while (1) {
        int temp;
        if (1 != scanf ("%d", &temp)) {
            printf ("ERROR: Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (INPUT_GUARD == temp) break;

        total += temp;
        ++count;
        switch (day_type(temp)) {
            case eHotDay : ++hot; break;
            case eColdDay : ++cold; break;
            case eCozyDay : ++cozy; break;
        }
    }
    double avgTemp = 0.0;
    if (count)
        avgTemp = (double)total / count;

    printf ("End\n\n");
    printf ("Total Hot days: %d \n", hot);
    printf ("Total Pleasant days: %d \n", cozy);
    printf ("Total Cold days: %d \n", cold);
    printf ("Average temperature for 8 days is %.2lf\n", avgTemp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good use of including _units_ in `#define HOT_CUTOFF  85  // Fahrenheit`.

Answer (score 0):

The first big mistake is here:

```
for(i = 0; i<8; i++ ){
 temp_ave =+ temp;     // You are not adding temp to temp_ave, to add you should
 }                     // write temp_ave += temp;
// Anyway this won't help you, cause you are trying to add the same number 8 times.
// So therefore it will give you wrong average, when you are calculating it.
```

I think this is what you wanted to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int categorize_days(int temp) {
    return (temp >= 85 ? 1 : (temp >= 60 ? 2 : 3));
}

int main() {
     int temp = 0, h = 0, p = 0, c = 0, cnt = -1;
     double ave = 0;

     printf("Lets check the whether !\n");
     printf("Keep entering the integer temperature, enter -1000 to quit\n\n");

    while (temp != -1000) {
        ave += temp;
        cnt ++;
        printf("Temperature: ");
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        int type_days = categorize_days(temp);

        if (type_days == 1) {
            printf ("Day: h\n\n");
            h++;
        }
        else if(type_days == 2) {
            printf ("Day: p\n\n");
            p++;
        }
        else {
            printf ("Day: c\n\n");
            c++;
        }
    }

    printf ("End\n\n");
    printf ("Total Hot days: %d \n", h);
    printf ("Total Pleasant days: %d \n", p);
    printf ("Total Cold days: %d \n", c);
    printf ("Average temperature for 8 days is %f", ave / cnt);
}
```

Comment: Yes. I got the right output now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> The average which is the last output should display 60 but I got it wrong.

This loop is a mess.  Same as `temp_ave = +temp;`, same as `temp_ave = temp;`.

```
for (i = 0; i<8; i++) {
  temp_ave =+ temp; // ????????
}
```

Instead:

```
temp_ave += temp; // Note +=
```

`temp_ave/8` in an `int` division.  Instead, perform the division per the type of `ave` avoiding casts.

```
// ave = temp_ave/8;
ave = temp_ave;
ave /= 8;  // Division done per wider of type of `ave` and `int` constant `8`.
```

> The total hot days should display 2 but on the output I got 3.

Enable all warnings.

Initialize `h, p, c`. [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71987777/the-output-for-average-is-not-correct/71989298#comment127202915_71987777)